# Appcompat SearchView icon?

Tags: android, searchview

I know I can change the icon in the menu xml like so:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/label_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

But I'm trying to setup my search theme in values/styles and the searchIcon key seems to do nothing.

In the below style, queryBackground works, closeIcon works, but searchIcon does nothing.  If I put the android:icon tag in the menu xml, it'll set it from there, but if I remove it, it just shows "Search" rather than the icon defined in the below style.

```
    <style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!--Background for the search query section (e.g. EditText)-->
    <item name="queryBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--Background for the actions section (e.g. voice, submit)-->
    <!--Close button icon-->
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/ic_cancel</item>
    <!--Search button icon-->
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: The search view is a menu item, the menu item definition defines what icons is shown, not the search view style.

Comment: I thought that may be the case... then why have it as a style?  sigh

Comment: The SearchView does not have to be in the menu. It may use the style if it is iconified and not in a menu.